# Read a list of value display it depends on pagesize and current page

Tags: java

- code feature: read a list of value display it depends on pagesize and current page
- original code:

```
public static <T> List<T> pageBySubList(List<T> list, int pagesize, int currentPage) {
        int totalcount = list.size();
        if (totalcount == 0) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        int pagecount = 0;
        List<T> subList;
        int m = totalcount % pagesize;
        if (m > 0) {
            pagecount = totalcount / pagesize + 1;
        } else {
            pagecount = totalcount / pagesize;
        }
        if (m == 0) {
            subList = list.subList((currentPage - 1) * pagesize, pagesize * (currentPage));
        } else {
            if (currentPage == pagecount) {
                subList = list.subList((currentPage - 1) * pagesize, totalcount);
            } else {
                subList = list.subList((currentPage - 1) * pagesize, pagesize * (currentPage));
            }
        }
        return subList;
    }
```

- first try:

```
  public static <T> List<T> pageBySubList(List<T> list, int pageSize, int currentPage) {
      if (list.isEmpty()) {
          return new ArrayList<>();
      }
      int pageCount = list.size() / pageSize + list.size() % pageSize > 0 ?  1 : 0;
      boolean isLastPage = list.size() % pageSize != 0 && currentPage == pageCount;
      return list.subList((currentPage - 1) * pageSize, isLastPage ? list.size() : pageSize * (currentPage));
  }
```

- second try:

```
public static <T> List<T> pageBySubList(List<T> list, int pageSize, int currentPage) {
      if (list.isEmpty()) {
          return new ArrayList<>();
      }
      int pageCount = list.size() / pageSize + list.size() % pageSize > 0 ?  1 : 0;
      boolean isLastPage = list.size() % pageSize != 0 && currentPage == pageCount;
      int pageStartLine = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
      int pageLastLine = isLastPage ? list.size() : pageSize * (currentPage);
      return list.subList(pageStartLine, pageLastLine);
  }
```

- one-line try, I think this one is the worst one which is worse than original one:

```
public static <T> List<T> pageBySubList(List<T> list, int pageSize, int currentPage) {
     return list.isEmpty() ? new ArrayList<>() : list.subList((currentPage - 1) * pageSize, (list.size() % pageSize != 0 && currentPage == (list.size() / pageSize + list.size() % pageSize > 0 ?  1 : 0)) ? list.size() : pageSize * (currentPage));
 }
```

question:

- Which one is better in maintainability and readability? In short, Temporary variables amount vs Readability
- Any better way to achieve it?

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## meaningful identifier

```
public ... pageBySubList(List<T> list, ...) {
```

That final identifier there, `list`, is just terrible.
Tell me what's *in* the list, tell me about its content.
From reading the signature I already know that `list` is a `List`,
so the name isn't being helpful.

OTOH `isLastPage` is a terrific identifier, very helpful.
The `pageStartLine` and `pageLastLine` names are nice, also.

## documentation

This function
[promises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
to do something.
But you don't spell out what that is,
you don't tell us about the post-condition.
There's no /** javadoc */,
and the English phrase "page by sub-list" is not sufficiently descriptive.

Let's put it this way.
Suppose I gave you specs for the three input parameters,
and an hour to write some code,
and I asked you to "please write a page by sub-list function",
which I'm going to examine for correctness and run tests against.
Would that be enough of a specification for you to code it up,
and be confident it would pass my functional tests?

We're looking for a sentence of javadoc which *would* allow you
to successfully accomplish that task.

## parallel structure

```
  int pageStartLine =                           (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
  int pageLastLine = isLastPage ? list.size() : pageSize * (currentPage);
```

nit: Please use the same order for factors in both assignments, with `pageSize` appearing first.

Yes, I know, multiplication commutes, and the machine doesn't care.
But people do.
You want to emphasize the similarity between what is being computed.

## level of abstraction

I agree with you that first and second try are definitely better than the original,
and that the one-liner is a non-starter.

It's a bit of a toss-up between the two, as either version would
make it past PR code review and get merged down to `main`.
I'm going to vote for the second try.
It introduces a pair of temp vars,
that is, it *names* intermediate expressions,
and in doing that it reveals higher level business concepts,
reveals what those expressions *mean*.

Ship it!

Comment: great answer! Sry I just miss copy-paste the javdoc and fix it a little by your advice. I'll accept your answer in a few days if no better answer.